# How to prevent app running in phone-gap from scrolling vertically?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I'm trying out phone gap and I want my application to not scroll up and down when the user drags their finger across the screen. This is my code. Can anyone tell me why it's still allowing scrolling?

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />-->

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <!-- iPad/iPhone specific css below, add after your main css >
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" type="text/css" />        
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" />       
    -->
    <!-- If you application is targeting iOS BEFORE 4.0 you MUST put json2.js from http://www.JSON.org/json2.js into your www directory and include it here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    // If you want to prevent dragging, uncomment this section
    /*
    function preventBehavior(e) 
    { 
      e.preventDefault(); 
    };
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);
    */

    /* If you are supporting your own protocol, the var invokeString will contain any arguments to the app launch.
    see http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
    for more details -jm */
    /*
    function handleOpenURL(url)
    {
        // TODO: do something with the url passed in.
    }
    */

    function onBodyLoad()
    {       
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    }

    /* When this function is called, PhoneGap has been initialized and is ready to roll */
    /* If you are supporting your own protocol, the var invokeString will contain any arguments to the app launch.
    see http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
    for more details -jm */
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        // do your thing!
        navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working")
    }
    touchMove = function(event) {
        // Prevent scrolling on this element
        event.preventDefault();
    }

</script>
<style>
#container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>

</head>

    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
        <div id="container" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 91):

if you're using **Cordova 2.3.0**+ find config.xml and add this line:

`<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />`

or in **Cordova 2.6.0**+:

`<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />`

Comment: Also pay attention to your meta `viewport` tag. The `width` value cannot be larger than the screen. It's tricky when your app's orientation is **landscape**. I use these values: `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=1024, height=768, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />` for landscape iPad application.

Answer (score 35):

Run this code when the page is loaded to disable dragging:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Here's an example with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
});
```

Comment: This prevents scroll even if there is content.

Comment: @techieWings I don't understand your comment... Did you read the question? That's exactly what the original poster is asking for.

Comment: yes, I have. I was just searching for something which wont allow page to overscroll but it can still scroll when there is scrollable content.

Answer (score 21):

in your config file use

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Comment: Here's the true(or very useful) answer. Surprised that only few of them voted for this answer.

Answer (score 10):

if you're using **Cordova 2.6.0+** find config.xml, just add/modify this line:

> `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />`

Comment: Works great. I wonder why this is not activated by default. Note that if you are using cordova-cli, the config.xml you have to modify is the one you'll find in your /www directory, not the one you have in /platforms/ios.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following entry to config.xml file:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say if this is a native app or a web app.

If this is a native app you can turn off scrolling on the webview

```
UIScrollView* scroll;  //
for(UIView* theWebSubView in self.webView.subviews){  // where self.webView is the webview you want to stop scrolling.
    if([theWebSubView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
        scroll = (UIScrollView*) theWebSubView;
        scroll.scrollEnabled = false;
        scroll.bounces = false;
    }
}
```

otherwise here is a link on the phonegap wiki for preventing scrolling.
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494815/Preventing-Scrolling-on-iPhone-Phonegap-Applications

Comment: It's native in the sense that's it's running inside phonegap's wrapper. Most people wouldn't call a web-app running inside a native wrapper a 'native app'

Comment: He said he's using phone gap and shows a bunch of HTML and CSS, how could it be a native app?

Answer (score 3):

In config.xml of your project, under preferences for iOS set DisallowOverscroll to true. By default it is false which makes whole view to scroll along with inner elements of the view.

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it work's perfect, when i use the body-selector with jquery. Otherwise i was not able to open external links with Phonegap.

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); 
})
```

Comment: Also works on a per page basis.`$('div#home').on('touchmove', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); 
})`

Answer (score 2):

Changed UIWebViewBounce to DisallowOverscroll in 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

now you just have to put `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />` to `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />` in your config.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Go native and add this line to the AppDelegate.m file

```
self.viewController.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
```

Drop it in the - ***(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*** section.

Answer (score 0):

At first what you have to do is you should add the event listener in body unload method.

simply put this line in the touch move method.

it won't scroll
document.addEventListener("touchstart/touchmove/touchend"). Any one of these 3.

```
function touchMove (event e) {
    e.preventDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have UIWebViewBounce to NO in your .plist file.

Then with simple css would make the content not scrollable. 
Try Adding this style **overflow : hidden** in your div where you want to disable the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

In config.xml of your project, under preferences for iOS set DisallowOverscroll to true.