# iPad prevent page drag

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, drag

I am writing an application for iPad using phonegap (Simple application using HTML5 and jQuery). The problem is the application window is draggable, as seen in image when I drag window down it comes down and when I leave window it goes up automatically. I don't want this behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the `UIWebViewBounce` to `NO` in your file `Cordova.plist`.

Check this link: [How to prevent app running in phone-gap from scrolling vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193016/how-to-prevent-app-running-in-phone-gap-from-scrolling-vertically)

**Note:** with this solution, you may disable the "landscape mode" of your app.

Hope this helps, let me know if this works for you mate