# Preventing iPad top page drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad

I'm trying for numerous days to solve the following issue.

I have a menu located on the top of the page which needed to be open using `swipedown` event (I'm using Hammer.js jQuery version).

Problem is, every time I try to interact using swipes I either scroll the page (`swipeup`) or pulling the page down same as described in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511485/ipad-prevent-page-drag).

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

`overflow: hidden;` on the `body` element with an inner container with `overflow: auto`, swipe on top element still triggered document scroll.

Setting `preventDefault` on the document also disabled lower elements events in the DOM hierarchy and by that I had no swipe events working in the page.

Also tried using `stopPropagation` on the actual element when the event occurs, to prevent the bubbling up the chain for the event, the result cause the object to not respond to the events (swipes) and document scroll worked with no problems.

Any ideas how can I still keep page scroll but also when using common gestures, such as swipedown/swipeup, on specific elements that the element only will be affected?

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xdydz/1/) using JSFiddle, to better demonstrate the issue.

Would appreciate ideas/thoughts

Comment: I realise you may be designing to a specification, but consider if swipe down is the best method to open this menu. Do user testing. Is it discoverable? Would a simple tap to the job better?

Comment: As for now I am using `tap` gesture, though `swipe` would be better fit since the menu slide from top when opening. (swiping just seems normal gesture to perform)

Comment: Get some data as to which is best - do some 'water cooler tests'. If you need the swipe to work will need to be on entire page, not just menu target

Comment: Thing is, only in the iOS devices causing the swipe event to always "bubble up" to the document (either html or body) while Android devices accept their fate with acceptance :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but I've always liked to use `drag` more than `swipe`. Using Hammer on my projects, swipes were a bit finicky. And from a UX standpoint, drag feels instantaneous vs a swipe. Much like, mousedown vs mouseup/click. So in instances where it's appropriate, and I believe in the case of showing swipey menu it is, I'd opt for `drag`.

Replacing your example with `drag` rather than `swipe`, and also using CSS transition, `-webkit-transition`, rather than jQuery's animate (drag will trigger like a mousemove, vs a click or a mouseup) seemed to make it work.

```
Hammer('.nav').on('dragdown', function(e){
    e.gesture.preventDefault()
    $(".blue").html("down")
    $('.nav').css({"top":"0px"});
})
.on('dragup', function(e){
    e.gesture.preventDefault()
    $(".blue").html("dragup")
    $('.nav').css({"top":"-150px"});
});

//Added in CSS, for .nav
.nav {-webkit-transition:0.5s top;}
```

[Example](http://mfirdaus.net/random/so/ios_scroll.htm)

This does still have the page overscroll. A `preventDefault()` on `document.ontouchstart` would could fix that but that breaks scrolling. You might be able to do a selective `preventDefault()` by checking the scrollOffset perhaps. But I guess in the long run, I'd recommend something like [**iScroll**](http://iscrolljs.com).

[Example](http://mfirdaus.net/random/so/ios_iscroll.htm)

Also maybe tweak the hitbox for the drag to be a bit larger. Which I did in the last example. I attached the `dragdown` event on the document instead of the "menu" so the menu doesn't have to be visibly bigger.

```
Hammer(document).on("dragdown",function(e){
    //calculate ratio of first touch from top
    var pos=e.gesture.startEvent.center.pageY/window.innerHeight

    if(pos<0.2){  //drag occurs in the first 20% of the screen
        menu.style.marginTop="0px" //or animate here
        e.gesture.preventDefault()
        e.gesture.stopPropagation();
    }
})
```

Comment: The first solution worked just fine. `swipe` really is problematic it seems. `dragup/down` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: As someone who is also enthusiastic about swipey menus, I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the preventDefault function of the orginal gesture, to stop the browsers default behaviour, see here: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Event-delegation-and-how-to-stopPropagation---preventDefaults

When you have a div element, on which you want to register swipe events, you would do the following:

```
$('#swipeDiv').hammer().on("swipe", function(ev) { ev.gesture.preventDefault(); });
```

That should prevent the scrolling of the page, but only if the swipe happens on the div element.

Comment: I still experience the page scrolling, I'll work on a JSFiddle example to better show the issue.