# Want Focus, but don't want scrolling iPhone web-app

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, scroll, focus

I am building an ios web app. I want to disable scrolling, so I used:

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and it works perfectly. However, now if the user taps on an input, it is not focused. "No big deal", I thought. This half fixes the problem:

```
$("div#searchBarView input").hammer().on("tap", function(){ //I'm using the hammer.js touch library.
    this.focus();
});
```

So now the keyboard comes up, but no cursor or blue focus-haze appear. If I type, then no text appears. Any ideas how to get the focus, but keep the scrolling off?

Thanks!

-Sean

Comment: have to tried using $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); ?

Comment: try giving the document a relative position with a -1 value for the z-index, and giving the input a relative position with a 1 value for the z-index

Comment: I forgot to mention: the body and html both are overflow:hidden and height:100%

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using JavaScript to prevent the scrolling, you might want to look at an alternative method, you should be able to prevent scrolling with pure CSS

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Then you can disable bounce with - [How to prevent app running in phone-gap from scrolling vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193016/how-to-prevent-app-running-in-phone-gap-from-scrolling-vertically)

Comment: I've seen this question and it refers to bounce, not scrolling. I want to stop the view from scrolling.

Comment: So I read that you already have overflow:hidden in a previous comment - what are your viewport settings?