# Scroll(Not moving a image) image in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, android, css, canvas, cordova

I am very much a beginner in canvas game development, so please forgive me for a silly question.

I have a image with 2048px width and 1536px height which I need to place in a canvas (width and height vary with different devices). I am able to scroll the image but the problem is that the image is coming out of the screen (showing white space in all the edges). Suppose devices width is 430 and height is 300 then user can scroll the image to see. If I swipe the screen for scrolling then image is coming out of the canvas just like pulling a rubber if I stop swiping image will place to canvas borders. Scrolling image is not fixing with canvas borders.. I am trying this since days.. Please anybody help me..

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
}

#inner {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
</style>


<!-- Adding viewport -->
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_v1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cityPrototype.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <canvas id="can1"> </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
  </html>
Here is Javascript function
function init(){  

can = document.getElementById('can');
cxt = can.getContext('2d');

can.width = can.parentNode.clientWidth;
can.height = can.parentNode.clientHeight;

 bg.onload=function(){
 alert("Onload");  

cxt.drawImage(bg,0,0,can.width,can.height);
width, height);
};
bg.src = "img/01.jpg";  
  }
```

I have searched before asking question but couldn't something perfect. I am running the app in PhoneGap framework using Canvas, JavaScript, and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, Finally I have found the answer, We can stop bouncing the screen by modifying  in the config.xml Found answer here [How to prevent app running in phone-gap from scrolling vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193016/how-to-prevent-app-running-in-phone-gap-from-scrolling-vertically)

Answer (score 0):

```
 #container {
width: 100%;
z-index:-1;

}

#inner {
overflow: auto;
}
```

Do not use width and height for inner. Just put your image into inner.

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/WY7fE/

Comment: Hi sir, Thanks for replying. Actually I need both horizantal and vertical scrolling and also I need to draw a image through canvas and I have canvas tag in html. Is it possible??

Comment: if you have one more image use command white-space:no wrap in canvas.

Comment: No, I have only one image, I want to put it into on canvas. I am running it in mobile devices, now also its coming out of the screen. Inner image is not setting with screen margins

Comment: After placing, the image will be scrolled into canvas, if you will use oferlow:auto for inner.

Comment: Yes I have checked that, but my problem is scrolling image in the canvas, it should not leave space edges, is it not possible to set the margins as 0 in css, Yes its possible but why its not working?